# Wpf set all columns to have the same default width

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to list a lot of items in a grid and i dont want to have to repeat "ColumnDefinition Width=40" from here on to infinity as i will need to add more TextBoxes with bindings.

Is there any way that i can set all columns to have width 40 so that i don't have to list everything?
I have tried using a UniformGrid, but i couldn't make it work properly.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewData}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type model:Character}">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MaxHealth}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Health}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding RegenerationSpeed}" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="4" IsChecked="{Binding Invincible}" Margin="10,3,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably more work than its worth, since you can't directly apply a Style for a grid's ColumnDefinitions.  I would probably just set a resource with your value (40) and use that.  At least you would only need to change the value one place, if you decided to change the value to 50 or something.  You can do that in XAML (in your ResourceDictionary if you have several controls etc. or the Window.Resources, whatever) like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <GridLength x:Key="stdWidth">40</stdWidth>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource stdWidth}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not quite what i was hoping for, but i guess that just has to work. Thanks